# Separate out interface from implementation with Swagger Codegen

Tags: c#, interface, swagger-codegen

Swagger Codegen generates lots of C# code, but one thing I'd like changed is the fact that it includes the Interface in the same file as the implementation.

```
namespace {{apiPackage}}
{
    {{#operations}}
    public interface I{{classname}}
    {
        {{#operation}}
        {{#returnType}}{{{returnType}}}{{/returnType}}{{^returnType}}double{{/returnType}} {{nickname}} ({{#allParams}}{{{dataType}}} {{paramName}}{{#hasMore}}, {{/hasMore}}{{/allParams}});
        {{/operation}}
    }

    public class {{classname}} : I{{classname}}
    { 
        public {{classname}}(ApiClient apiClient = null)
        {
            // code omitted...
```

Is there anyway to separate out the interface into a separate file? This isn't modifying the current template, but more specifically adding a new one. The above code snippet comes from `api.mustache` and in this scenario, I'd like to add another template for Swagger Codegen to use, titled something along the lines of `api_interface.mustache`

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to configure the source code file header generated by Swagger Codegen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50165530/113116)

Comment: @Helen Thanks for the comment, but that question seems to relate to modifying existing templates, whereas I'm asking if there's a way to basically create more templates. I'll update the question with some more detail to explain the problem a bit better.